# Resolve Typescript and F-Bounded Polymorphism

Tags: typescript

I have 3 kinds of Parsers in [Masala Parser](https://github.com/d-plaindoux/masala-parser/blob/master/masala-parser.d.ts). `SingleParser<Y>` returns a `Y` value, `ArrayParser<Y>` returns an `Array<Y>`, `VoidParser` returns nothing.
They all are `IParser<Y>` that contains many common functions.

It runs on javascript, but I want to make the **masala.d.ts** type file. I would like to optimize the `map()` that is no repeated:

```
export interface IParser<T> {

    map<Y> (f: (T) => Y): IParser<Y>;
    // common functions
    debug(s:string, b?:boolean); // ... others
}

interface VoidParser extends IParser<void> {
    map<Y> (f: (T) => Y): VoidParser<Y>;
}

export interface SingleParser<T> extends IParser<T> {
    map<Y> (f: (T) => Y): SingleParser<Y>;
}

export interface ArrayParser<T> extends IParser<T> {
    map<Y> (f: (T) => Y): ArrayParser<Y>;
}
```

They are many functions like `map()` and I would like to simplify IParser using **this** :

```
export interface IParser<T> {

    map<Y> (f: (T) => Y): this<Y>;
    // common functions ...
}
```

Unfortunately `this<Y>` is not accepted here (using typescript 2.6 or 3.0). What is the correct syntax ?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't really a correct syntax; TypeScript doesn't support [higher kinded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), which is what you're looking for.  There have been various attempts at workarounds, but nothing elegant enough for me to suggest here.

Comment: OK. For what I've seen in your link, I will just Do Repeat Myself for this time

Comment: I'm confused about your definitions.  They don't compile in `strict` mode and I don't understand what you intend.  You can't have a function type  like `f: (T)=>Y`.  Well, you *can*, but TypeScript interprets this as `f: (T: any)=>Y`, where `T` is a parameter name, not a type.  You need to do something like `f: (x:T)=>Y`.

Comment: Once you fix that I'm still confused.  If `VoidParser` extends `IParser<void>`, then the `map` function should only be able to take a callback expecting a `void`, not a `T`... and there is no `T` anyway.  And the output type is a `VoidParser<Y>` but `VoidParser` is not generic.  So `Y` is just void?  So `f` is a function from `void` to `void`?  If you could fix these up I might have a less repetitive workaround but it's impossible to know right now.